# WPF what happens when a one way bound property is manually modified

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm just curious. For example, if the width of a custom user control is bound to the actual width of some other usercontrol, but then the width in the usercontrol is manually changed during some event. Will the property just go out of sync? Will the binding not work correctly? or will the property just be out of sync until the next time the source property changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more differentiation required. First: What kind of binding is it? If you have a OneWay binding then you will get out of sync when the target gets modified.
TwoWay or OneWayToSource will cause an update of the source (feed back)

In the case of OneWay changing the value will not remote the binding, as @goose noted when the source will trigger a PropertyChanged event the target destination will be resynced again.

If you wish to remove the binding, call BindingExpression.ClearBinding with the DependencyProperty you want to clear or BindingExpression.ClearAllBindings.

Answer (score 0):

When a one way bound property is modified the binding will no longer work correctly. Even when the property is altered afterwards using the set method and NotifyPropertyChanged properly the width will remain unchanged.